# Selenium Web Driver : Not able to perform operation on new tab

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I am not able to perform operation on new `tab`.

Consider the following scenario : Add a ticket, after adding ticket, page goes to view tickets page (all the actions are performed on same tab). On this page,i got three options `View`, `Edit` and `delete` tickets. If i click on View or edit icon the new tab is get opened.

Everything are performed till above but after opening new tab, `selenium ide` doesn't recognise or not able to perform operations on newly opened `tab`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide a [mcve] so that others have a chance to provide you with a helpful answer.

Comment: Please, post your script and HTML. At least.